# Problems packaging apps with Jersey deps into jars

Tags: java, jar, jersey, jackson

My group publishes executable jars (not applets, just to be clear) for nearly all of our functionality. One of our new executables is a Web service client that relies on Jersey. I'm trying to use the automatic POJO mapping facility to unmarshal responses (i.e., I have JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING set to true in the ClientConfig) but when I execute the jar I get the "I don't know how to unmarshal this response" message:

`SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class edu.mit.broad.picard.bass.GetSite, and Java type class edu.mit.broad.picard.bass.GetSite, and MIME media type application/json was not found`

The app works just fine if I run it from my IDE (IntelliJ). I'm assuming it's a problem with the way in which the jar file is packaged but I don't know the details of Jersey (or Jackson, for that matter) well enough to get this fixed. Any hints?

This is Java 1.7, Jersey bundle 1.17.1 and Jackson 1.9.13. All the `com/sun/**/*` and `org/codehaus/**/*` files are being included in the jar.

Thanks for your help!!

Edit:
I checked the META-INF dir for the needed .../services dir. Here's what's in it:

```
cm59f-0fa:zamboni jrose$ jar tvf GenerateGetSite.jar | grep META-INF | grep services
    0 Thu Aug 15 10:43:32 EDT 2013 META-INF/services/
    0 Thu Feb 28 15:29:04 EST 2013 META-INF/services/com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceMethodDispatchProvider
  514 Thu Feb 28 15:29:04 EST 2013 META-INF/services/com.sun.jersey.spi.HeaderDelegateProvider
  563 Thu Feb 28 15:29:04 EST 2013 META-INF/services/com.sun.jersey.spi.StringReaderProvider
  147 Thu Feb 28 15:29:04 EST 2013 META-INF/services/com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerProvider
   60 Thu Feb 28 15:29:04 EST 2013 META-INF/services/com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilter
    0 Thu Feb 28 15:29:04 EST 2013 META-INF/services/com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilter
  377 Wed Feb 27 20:17:28 EST 2013 META-INF/services/com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ResourceMethodCustomInvokerDispatchProvider
  376 Wed Feb 27 20:17:28 EST 2013 META-INF/services/com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ResourceMethodDispatchProvider
   64 Thu Feb 28 15:29:04 EST 2013 META-INF/services/com.sun.jersey.spi.container.WebApplicationProvider
  267 Thu Feb 28 15:29:04 EST 2013 META-INF/services/com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.InjectableProvider
   44 Wed Feb 27 20:17:06 EST 2013 META-INF/services/javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension
  882 Mon Dec 19 14:53:22 EST 2011 META-INF/services/javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory
   79 Wed Feb 27 20:17:06 EST 2013 META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
 2880 Thu Feb 28 15:29:04 EST 2013 META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader
 2654 Thu Feb 28 15:29:04 EST 2013 META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter
   56 Thu Feb 28 15:29:04 EST 2013 META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would be that you are creating one jar that contains the contents of all of your jar dependencies. If this is the case, the issue is probably due to improper construction of your one jar. Jersey relies on resources in META-INF/services for its proper operation. You need to make sure that the contents of META-INF/services get merged into your one jar.

One option that is working for me is the maven-shade-plugin, which includes a transformer that does exactly this merging:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Hm, just checked META-INF and it has the services dir, including provider classes. I'll add the list of what's there to the original posting.

Comment: You need to make sure that all of the provider classes listed in the various jars get listed in your repackaged jar.

Comment: That's it! I had included all the com.sun and org.codehaus classes but not the javax ones.